# Microsoft Graph- Do we need specific Office365 license to use Webhooks?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

There is a minimum Office365 license to use Webhook with Microsoft Graph? 
From here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-beta I cannot find any details about it.

Answer (score 1):

No extra license is required for change notifications (webhooks) for most resources. The only license requirement is on the service itself: if you want to subscribe to messages (emails) it requires the user to have an Office 365 license that includes Exchange online.

For Teams: Change Notification API for Teams allMessages resources might be required to have subscriptions to specific Microsoft 365 offerings. Upon general availability, Microsoft may require you or your customers to pay additional fees based on the amount of data accessed through the API.